# window.onresize event deletes d3 data from chart object

Tags: javascript, d3.js, constructor, window-resize

I have created a js constructor function to create a D3 chart object.

The function appears to work on initial load. However,I have also added an `onresize` listener to re-draw the chart on resize.

However, when the resize event occurs, a console.log() of the data used to make the chart shows that the `dates` field (the first field) is all `null`. I have not been successful in using console.log to find where this change actually occurs. The data seems normal before the resize and before the chart drawing function runs.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tz1kvwpg/), which as the full code. When you resize the viewport, the chart disappears. console shows `myData` is `null`

Relevant code:

HTML

```
var firstChart = new LineChart(myData,'chart-container','chart_area','This Is A Chart',["red","yellow","blue"],"temp","date")

        //Re draw on resize
        window.onresize = function(){

            firstChart.drawChart();
            console.log(myData);
        }
```

DATA

```
    var myData = [
    {"date":20111001,"New_York":63.4,"San_Francisco":62.7,"Austin":72.2},
    {"date":20111002,"New_York":58,"San_Francisco":59.9,"Austin":67.7},
    {"date":20111003,"New_York":53.3,"San_Francisco":59.1,"Austin":69.4},
    {"date":20111004,"New_York":55.7,"San_Francisco":58.8,"Austin":68},
    {"date":20111005,"New_York":64.2,"San_Francisco":58.7,"Austin":72.4},
    {"date":20111006,"New_York":58.8,"San_Francisco":57,"Austin":77},
    {"date":20111007,"New_York":57.9,"San_Francisco":56.7,"Austin":82.3},
    {"date":20111008,"New_York":61.8,"San_Francisco":56.8,"Austin":78.9},
    {"date":20111009,"New_York":69.3,"San_Francisco":56.7,"Austin":68.8},
    {"date":20111010,"New_York":71.2,"San_Francisco":60.1,"Austin":68.7},
    {"date":20111011,"New_York":68.7,"San_Francisco":61.1,"Austin":70.3},
    {"date":20111012,"New_York":61.8,"San_Francisco":61.5,"Austin":75.3},
    {"date":20111013,"New_York":63,"San_Francisco":64.3,"Austin":76.6},
    {"date":20111014,"New_York":66.9,"San_Francisco":67.1,"Austin":66.6},
    {"date":20111015,"New_York":61.7,"San_Francisco":64.6,"Austin":68},
    {"date":20111016,"New_York":61.8,"San_Francisco":61.6,"Austin":70.6},
    {"date":20111017,"New_York":62.8,"San_Francisco":61.1,"Austin":71.1},
    {"date":20111018,"New_York":60.8,"San_Francisco":59.2,"Austin":70},
    {"date":20111019,"New_York":62.1,"San_Francisco":58.9,"Austin":61.6},
    {"date":20111020,"New_York":65.1,"San_Francisco":57.2,"Austin":57.4},
    {"date":20111021,"New_York":55.6,"San_Francisco":56.4,"Austin":64.3}
]
```

On resize the date column is all `null`

JS

```
function LineChart(data,chartContainerID,chartAreaId,chartTitle,colorArray,yaxisLabel,xaxisLabel,legend,yaxisFormat, marginsDict){

        this.data = data;
        this.chartContainer = document.getElementById(chartContainerID)
        this.chartArea = document.getElementById(chartAreaId);
        this.chartTitle = chartTitle;
        this.colors = colorArray;
        this.yaxisLabel=yaxisLabel;
        this.xaxisLabel=xaxisLabel;
        this.isLegend = legend;
        this.yaxisFormat= yaxisFormat;
        this.margins = marginsDict;

///....more code here in js fiddle.....


this.drawChart = function(){


///....more code here in js fiddle.....


///Console leads me here. more code above it
   var items = color.domain().map(function(name) {

          return {
            name: name,
            values: data.map(function(d) {
                console.log(d)
              return {
                date: d.date,
                result: +d[name]
              };
            })
          };
        });

///....more code here in js fiddle.....

}
}
```

Comment: `console` leads you there because `color` is undefined? Can't see the code.

Comment: This is a sample. The jsfiddle has the full code, which is long. color should be defined

Comment: Because you are trying to parse already parsed values. Just do this in the constructor and not in the drawChart method. https://jsfiddle.net/c3vhakjb/ Voting to close as "won't help future readers".

Comment: I see. thank you. I didn't realize the parser changed the actual object